# Sort MYSQL TABLES using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, button, sql-order-by

I have a table that sorts the name by ASC order but when i click the button it doesn't work. 
I tried doing the same with 2 buttons and checked some of the codes available but it doesn't work at all. Any help?

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myfeeds";

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed");
    }

    $db = mysql_select_db("myfeeds", $conn);
    if (!$db) {
        die("Can't select database");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['asc'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name ASC");
    } else {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name DESC");

    }

    if (!$result) {
        die("Failed to show queries from table");
    }


    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Here's the button:

```
SORT BY:  
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <button type="submit" id="asc" name="asc">ASC</button>
            </form>
```

Table:

```
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Logo</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    $i = 0;

                    while ($i < $num) {
                        $f5 = mysql_result($result, $i, "id");
                        $f1 = mysql_result($result, $i, "name");
                        $f2 = mysql_result($result, $i, "url");
                        $f3 = mysql_result($result, $i, "description");
                        $f4 = mysql_result($result, $i, "image");
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<img src='$f4'>"; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $i++;
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql_numrows` is invalid. That should read as `mysql_num_rows`. Plus, where are you echoing your results? It's not in what you posted. You need to echo those.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Doing `die("Message X")` doesn't help.

Comment: Try `<input type="submit">`

Comment: And DO NOT use `mysql_*`! These are deprecated, and it is time you moved on to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: @CEP `<button type="submit" id="asc" name="asc">ASC</button>` is valid. Had the OP used `<button type="button" id="asc" name="asc">ASC</button>` then it would not have worked. OP's error is either elsewhere and is not showing it, or if it's the exact code that is using, isn't doing anything with the query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Noted, thanks :) That is new to me. And yes, I think OP is not not doing anything with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. working 100% =)

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myfeeds";

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed");
    }

    $db = mysql_select_db("myfeeds", $conn);
    if (!$db) {
        die("Can't select database");
    }

    if (isset($_GET['asc']))
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name ASC");
    else
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name DESC");


    if (!$result)
        die("Failed to show queries from table");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    mysql_close();

?>

<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" id="asc" name="asc" value="asc">ASC</button>
    <button type="submit" id="asc" name="desc" value="desc">DESC</button>
</form>
```

it is better to use PDO this is how..

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myfeeds";


    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }


    try
    {
        if (isset($_GET['asc']))
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name ASC");
        else
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name DESC");

        $result->execute();

        if($result->rowCount())
        {
            while($r = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
                echo 'Name:' . $r->name . '<br/>';
            }
        }
        else echo 'no record found!';

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

Viewing datas from database using mysql

```
<table cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["url"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<img src='".$row["image"]."'>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php

    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @jmn I tried your codes and it works but I don't how to implement it using my table output.

Comment: @jmn how can i send it to you?

Comment: i already edited the code and added how to view information from database

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), the fourth parameter of `mysql_connect` should be a new link of connection, not the database name.

> **new_link**
>
> If a second call is made to `mysql_connect()` with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. >The **new_link** parameter modifies this behavior and makes `mysql_connect()` always open a new link, even if `mysql_connect()` was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

I suggest use `mysqli_*` instead, since mysql is deprecated.

And of course, don't forget to fetch the rows after the query.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myfeeds";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$order = isset($_POST['asc']) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY name $order";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$num = $query->num_rows;
if($num > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: *"According to the manual, the fourth parameter of mysql_connect should be a new link of connection, not the database name."* - Well I feel like a real "duh" lol +1 ;) just goes to show how much about `mysql_` I know. I'm a "mysqli/PDO" guy.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah i thought i was seeing mysqli at first, but it was mysql_connect, and having that `$dbname` in there was a bit off.

Comment: OP using `die("Connection failed")` doesn't help neither. `die(mysql_error())` is better.

Comment: @Fred-ii- surprisingly yes of course after fixing the num rows

Comment: @Ghost Thank you for the advice. I'm new to mysql and php. I'm just referring everything from our lecture notes.

Comment: @Kamilah and my advice to you is to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead since you're starting out. i suggest read this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php for mysqli or this one http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers for PDO. personally i'd take PDO